# What percentage of China speak Hokkien/Taiwanese?

Tags: hokkien

The top 5 languages spoken in china are:

Mandarin
Cantonese
Hokkien
Shanghainese
Hakka

But I can't find what percentage of China speak Hokkien

Answer (score 2):

Exact percentage is hard to determine since there can be

- People grown up in XX Province not knowing how to speak the dialect (as is my case)
- People who was born in YY Province and, having worked in ZZ province for decades, learns how to speak the dialect there.

So...

- Mandarin: Originated from Beijing and is taught everywhere, as everyone is required to go through at least 9 years of education, nearly everyone can speak it except some old people.
- Cantonese: Spoken in Guangdong Province, Hong Kong and Macau mainly, at most 85 million people speak it if you count all sub-dialects
- Hokkien: Spoken in Fujian Province, Taiwan, Philippines, and other S Asian countries, 20 million people within China speak it, while 30 million outside do.
- Hakka: Spoken in Guangdong mainly and has a speaker of around 50 million
- Shanghainese: is a variety of the Wu dialect, has ~14 million speakers.

Numbers are grabbed from their respective Wikipedia pages.

Answer (score 2):

source：https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%97%BD%E5%8D%97%E8%AF%AD

于2017年，全球以闽南语（包括海南话等）为母语的人数约为7000万人，其中中国大陆的闽南语人口（包括海南话）则是2710万人（2013）[1]。全球闽南语以使用者人口排名并非定值而会浮动，估计位居世界第20~30名之间。

2710万/14亿=1.94%

About 2% of people in China speak Hokkien